# If $\int_{0}^{x}\{t\}dt = \int_{0}^{\{x\}}tdt$ and $x>0$ and $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$, Then $x$ is

Tags: calculus

If $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\{t\}dt = \int_{0}^{\{x\}}tdt$ and $x>0$ and $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $\{x\} = $ fractional part of $x$ i.e $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x \rfloor $.

Then value of $x$ is

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given  $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\{t\}dt = \int_{0}^{\{x\}}tdt\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x}\left(t-\lfloor t \rfloor \right)dt = \int_{0}^{\{x\}}tdt$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x}tdt - \int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor dt = \int_{0}^{\{x\}}tdt\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2}-I=\frac{\{x\}^2}{2}..............(1)$

Now For calculation of $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor dt$

Now Let $n\leq t <n+1\;,$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, Then $\lfloor t \rfloor = n$

So $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{x}\lfloor t \rfloor dt = \int_{0}^{1}0dt+\int_{1}^{2}1dt+.........+\int_{n-1}^{n}(n-1)dt+\int_{n}^{x}ndt$

So $\displaystyle I = 0+1+2+3+..........+(n-1)+n(x-n) = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n(x-n)$

So $\displaystyle I = \frac{n}{2}(n-1+2x-2n)=\frac{n}{2}(2x-n-1)=\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor }{2}\left(2x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)$

Put into equation.......$(1)$

So $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor }{2}\left(2x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right) = \frac{\{x\}^2}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-\{x\}^2\right) = \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor }{2}\left(2x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1\right)$

So $\displaystyle \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \left(x+\{x\}\right) = \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \left(2x-\lfloor x \rfloor -1\right)$

So ether $\lfloor x \rfloor = 0\Rightarrow x\in \mathbb{Z}$(Which is not possible.) OR

$\displaystyle x+\{x\} = 2x-\{x\}-1\Rightarrow x = 2\{x\}+1$

Now How can i solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Comment: $x=2\langle x\rangle +1\implies x=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \left(x+\langle x\rangle\right) = \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \left(2x-\lfloor x \rfloor -1\right)$

- if $\lfloor x \rfloor=0\implies x\in[0,1)$
- if $\lfloor x \rfloor\ne0$, then $x=2\langle x\rangle +1\implies x-\langle x\rangle=\langle x\rangle+1\implies\lfloor x \rfloor-1= \langle x\rangle$, since both sides must be integers $\langle x\rangle=0\implies x\in\mathbb Z$ **Contradiction**

  ---

Using concept of area:
[image]
$$\int_0^x\langle x\rangle dx=\frac12\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac12\langle x\rangle^2\\
\int_0^{\langle x\rangle}tdt=\frac12\langle x\rangle ^2 $$
So $\lfloor x\rfloor=0\implies x\in[0,1)$

Comment: @juantheron see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^x_0\{t\}dt = \int_0^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\{t\}dt+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^{x}\{t\}dt
\ge 0 +\int_0^{\{x\}}tdt.
$$
**Edit:** I just noticed that you also proved that $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$. That simply means $x<1$.